# How to use column value as column name?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with some columns with data plus a column containing column names:

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  "aa" = 11:15,
  "ab" = 21:25,
  "ac" = 31:35,
  "nn" = c("aa", "aa", "ac", "ab", "aa"))
```

I would like to get a vector from columns "aa", "ab", or "ac". That column name for every row is specified in the "nn" column.

So I should get `11, 12, 33, 24, 15`.

Can this be done without loops? `mydf[mydf$nn]` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` to return the index of column names and then create a row/column index to extract the values

```
mydf[-4][cbind(seq_len(nrow(mydf)), match(mydf$nn, names(mydf)))]
#[1] 11 12 33 24 15
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `cbind` and create a row-column index and then use it to subset the dataframe.

```
mydf[cbind(1:nrow(mydf), mydf$nn)]
#[1] "11" "12" "33" "24" "15"
```

Or if you know they are going to be number always

```
as.numeric(mydf[cbind(1:nrow(mydf), mydf$nn)])
#[1] 11 12 33 24 15
```

where

```
cbind(1:nrow(mydf), mydf$nn) #gives

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    2    1
#[3,]    3    3
#[4,]    4    2
#[5,]    5    1
```